# Unable to install icaclient ("Errors were encountered while processing")

Tags: apt

I tried to installed icaclient (a remote desktop application), and it failed to install for some reason. The problem is that now whenever I try to install a new application with apt-get, I get this message even of the installation succeeded:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Although applications do get installed correctly, but the message is really annoying, and it could potentially hide other errors.

Comment: IMHO `icaclient` isn't installed properly. If it doesn't break any dependency, try to uninstall it first with `aptitude remove icaclient:i386`. Also always force yourself to use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`. It's way more "smart".

Comment: @Avio while aptitude may be more smart, it sometimes breaks on multi-arch things, i.e. on amd64, :i386 isnt completely working.  I'd recommend for uninstalling to use apt-get, then installing to try to use aptitude, but... it might not work.

Comment: Well that's because you shouldn't mix i386 and amd64 packages as well as you shouldn't mix Ubuntu and Debian packages. `aptitude` applies stricter dependency rules and sanity checks than `apt-get`. If you chose to break this rules is ok, but you have to know that _you_ are breaking the rules, it's not `aptitude` that is dumb :P (Well sometimes, it's really dumb, but fortunately in rare occasions.)

Comment: Look at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/icaclient.postinst`. If it begins with `#!/bin/sh`, add `set -x` as the second line. If it doesn't, post a link to the package so we can see how to see get more verbose messages. Then run `sudo apt-get -f install` and copy-paste the complete trace.

Comment: @Avio, I tried your solution (with apt-get instead of aptitude) and it did work! Thanks very much. Maybe you want to post it as an answer so that I mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO `icaclient` isn't installed properly. If it doesn't break any dependency, try to uninstall it first with `aptitude remove icaclient:i386`. Also always force yourself to use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`. It's way more "smart".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this page](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/)

Try this

1. `cd /var/lib/dpkg/info`
2. `sudo rm icaclient:i386.*`
3. `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq icaclient:i386`

Comment: I tried @Avio's suggestion in the comment above and it works, so no need to do things manually :-)

Comment: In that case, @Avio post this as an answer so [Promather](http://askubuntu.com/users/7280/promather) can accept this as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `apt-get -f install`

then

`apt-get upgrade`

and the try to install a new application.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: @Promather send more output!

Comment: There is nothing more to send, I just keep getting the same error.

Comment: @Promather Well I don't think that you had only these 3 lines as an output.

Comment: True, but the rest are just the normal `apt-get` information lines, and they are irrelevant. The three lines I mentioned are the only error lines.